# Create a list with rotation

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to figure out the best method to achieve this, but can't think of anything and don't find to much on the big internet.

But this is what I would like to achieve; A list and on each `<li>` rotate -45deg

```
li {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    border: solid 1px #828080;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg); 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    position: relative;
    margin: 33px;
}
```

And should look like something like this (Hope you get the idea, with my bad photoshop-skills)
[image]

And here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkpxy9mn/) with the simple stuff:

Comment: Put the rotate on the `ul`, not the `li`.

Comment: @putvande: But the size of the `ul` will either be fixed or set `position` and `top/left`. And with that it won't work that well with responsive?

Comment: I don't understand. Why would it work if you put the rotate on the `li` and not on the `ul`?

Comment: is the layout fixed?

Comment: Well, the idea is to have a dynamic list, and will just repeat the format for each `li` thats gets added.

Answer (score 3):

The `rotate` goes on the `ul` and remove the `margin` from your `li`:

```
.picker {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
     transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg); 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
}

li {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    border: solid 1px #828080;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkpxy9mn/1/)

Comment: Yeah, but it won't fill the whole wrapper element. Without white-space

Comment: That is a different question. Your drawing doesn't looks like the Fiddle in my answer.

Comment: Well, thats why is wrote the numbers also. If it would be to hard to understand. By setting the rotate on `ul`, it will create white-space as you can see. Then I can just rotate the `wrapper` and not `ul`.

Comment: So you want to fill the whole wrapper with the `ul` / `li`?

Comment: Yeah, I have inserted some images in some of the `li`. Check out updated question. It maybe explains it better?

Comment: Your two drawings don't match.